# Logging in using facebook/twitter account

Tags: iphone, android, facebook, twitter

I am developing an iPhone application, which has a registration feature as well. Now, I would like to enable those users who already have account with facebook or twitter to login directly using their FB/Twitter credentials.

Pl. help me with this.

Comment: You should accept answers to some of your previous questions before posting new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SDK for facebook connect for the iPhone: [Facebook iPhone SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk)

For Twitter, you could try this? [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)

Answer (score 1):

Twitter's offering is called **[Sign in with Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter)**, and Facebook offers **[Login with Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login)**.

These links should get you started.